# Deserializing an object containing a Dictionary parameter results in the dictionary becoming a null object

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net

This json object contains a list of Person  object which each have a dictionary on them.

```
{
  "$type": "PeopleDataObject, Assembly-CSharp",
  "People": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Person, Assembly-CSharp]], 
                                                                 mscorlib",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$type": "Person, Assembly-CSharp",
        "Id": 0,
        "FirstName": "Daffy",
        "LastName": "Duck",
        "Age": 0,
        "Sex": true,
        "Stats": {
          "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, 
                            mscorlib],[System.Int32, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
          "str": 9,
          "dex": 13,
          "con": 9,
          "int": 13,
          "wis": 10,
          "cha": 8
        }
      },
      {
        "$type": "Person, Assembly-CSharp",
        "Id": 1,
        "FirstName": "Wilma",
        "LastName": "Flintstone",
        "Age": 0,
        "Sex": false,
        "Stats": {
          "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, 
            mscorlib],[System.Int32, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
          "str": 7,
          "dex": 9,
          "con": 9,
          "int": 12,
          "wis": 12,
          "cha": 12
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "Count": 2
}
```

I checked that the string read doesn't come out malformed by writing the it to another file so I know that everything serializes correctly but on deserialization the dictionaries are lost so that when I go to use it or save it again they're null. The debugger identifies it as a null object. The code below follows the documentation for general objects but I couldn't find a specific case for objects containing dictionaries. I made sure to include TypeNameHandling so as to try to make sure it knew to deserialize into a dictionary but I'm not getting that result.

```
private void LoadRoster()
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "PeopleData.json");
    string debug = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "debug.json");
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        Debug.Log("NO SAVE FILE RECOGNISED");
    }
    else
    {
        PeopleDataObject allPeople = PeopleDataObject.Instance;
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(path);

        //check that the file is read correctly
        File.WriteAllText(debug, jsonString);

        allPeople = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PeopleDataObject>(jsonString, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
        });
        People = allPeople.People;
        Person.AllTimeCount = allPeople.Count;
        Debug.Log("Loaded");
    }
}
```

Edit: It's trying to deserialize to the following PeopleDataObject class which itself contains a list of Person which I will also provide below.

PeopleDataObject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PeopleDataObject
{
    //<Singleton Boilerplate>
    private static PeopleDataObject instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    PeopleDataObject() {}

    public static PeopleDataObject Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock(padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new PeopleDataObject();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
    //</Singletone Boilerplate>

    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Person:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Person
{

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }
    public bool Sex { get; private set; } //true = male, false = female
    public Dictionary<string, int> Stats { get; private set; }

    public static int AllTimeCount { get; set; }

    private GameObject messageController;

    public Person(string first, string last, bool sex, GameObject controller)
    {
        Debug.Log(" overload 1");
        FirstName = first;
        LastName = last;
        Age = 0;
        Sex = sex;
        Id = AllTimeCount;
        AllTimeCount++;

        if (controller != null)
            messageController = controller;
        else
            messageController = GameObject.Find("PersonManager");

        //if sex is true (male) colour modifier is blue, else colour modifier is pink
        string colourMod = sex ? "#4286f4" : "#ff56ff";

        Notification(string.Format("<{0}>{1} {2}</color> was born. ", colourMod, first, last));

    }

    public Person(int id, string first, string last, bool sex, Dictionary<string, int> stats)
    {
        Debug.Log("overload 2");
        Id = id;
        FirstName = first;
        LastName = last;
        Sex = sex;
        Stats = stats;
    }

    public Person()
    {
        Debug.Log("overload 3");
    }

    public void SetStats(Dictionary<string, int> s)
    {
        Stats = s;
    }

    public void IncrementAge()
    {
        Age++;
    }

    public void Notification(string message)
    {
        MessageController controller = messageController.GetComponent<MessageController>();
        controller.PostMessage(message);
    }
}
```

By the way I am aware that messageController in Person is null when constructors 2 or 3 are used but that's not my concern right now and it has no bearing on the current issue but it will be seen to.

Edit Edit: Have tried TypeHandling.Auto instead of TypeHandling.All and it has no effect.

I've been stuck on this for some time. I already know I'm an idiot but I'd much appreciate a helping hand to tell me why I'm an idiot.

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Without the definition of the PeopleDataObject, which controls the serialization, we can’t help.

Comment: Show the code of your classes.

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] of this to help you.  See [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for some tips how to write questions that we are likely to be able to answer.

Comment: Ah sorry. I thought I might post too much code and look like I'm not trying. Edited to include PeopleDataObject and Person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be the accessability of my properties.

I was using `{ get; private set; }` on Age, Sex and Stats because I thought best practice was to control the accessibility but I should have been using `{ get; set }` so that the json library has access to write the values to the object on deserialization.

It was just more obvious for the dictionaries because the Age int defaults to zero and all my test people were 0 year old infants anyway; sex defaults to false (female) which I just didn't spot; dictionary defaults to null and you lose a lot of data so it's the symptom I noticed.